# Issue with model summary in keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

The following code appears to have no error, but does not display the model with or without a print statement preceding the "model.summarize" statement. I am new to this so this code may be very bad.
Edit: Again I am new to this, all I want to do is verify that I have a working model with the summary utility. Am I missing a lot if so do you know of any good documentation on this.

```
from keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from sys import setrecursionlimit
from keras.optimizers import Adam

setrecursionlimit(10000)


class DQN:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.epsilon = 0.1
        self.hidden_layers = 4
        self.shape = (None, 200)
        self.input_units = 256
        self.ouput_units = 256
        self.hidden_units = 512
        self.learning_rate = 0.005

    def get_model(self):
        model = Sequential()

        model.add(layers.GRU(self.input_units, input_shape=self.shape, return_sequences=True))
        for layer in range(self.hidden_layers):
            model.add(layers.GRU(self.hidden_units, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(layers.GRU(self.ouput_units, return_sequences=True))
        model.summary
```

Comment: You do not seem to be calling model.summary, the parenthesis are missing, it should be model.summary()

Comment: I have tried that as well

Comment: You need to be very specific on your problem, we cannot guess.

Comment: It displays absolutely nothing, I want it to display model information.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Where are you running this code? This code just defines a class, it does not execute any usable code at all. If you run it it will not print anything.

Comment: I have a class and I have added layers to a model within that class, now what is the minimum I need to add to get it to display information about said model

Comment: Like @Dr.Snoopy said, you defined the class but never instantiated it as an object. Even if you instantiated it and called `get_model()`, you never save the model as an object attribute anywhere, and hence the model would likely get lost upon method execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DQN:
    def __init__(self, env):
        pass

    def get_model(self):
        model = Sequential()

        model.add(layers.GRU(self.input_units, input_shape=self.shape, return_sequences=True))
        for layer in range(self.hidden_layers):
            model.add(layers.GRU(self.hidden_units, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(layers.GRU(self.ouput_units, return_sequences=True))
        print(model.summary())

target = DQN()
target.get_model()
```

Give this a try..!

Comment: It works! I did some experimenting and found out that print(model.summary()) can just be model.summary, but other than that it's great. Thank you